# Correct skinning is still not deforming my mesh

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I just skinned a small model and ran into a little problem with that. I skinned with vertex groups, so I applied all vertices that should be deformed by a certain bone to the vertex group "cube_bone". The bone has the same name of course.

When I look in weight paint mode now, everything looks like its supposed to:

[image]

When I now want to try a pose, this is what happens:

[image]

Actually its correct that the blue spheres are moving, since they are controlled by the childreen of the bone I am trying to skin. But what is wrong with the "cube_bone" ? Or why do the vertices not move at all?

I also found out, at the "Vertex Weight" Toolbar under "deform" there is no bone applied, only under "all".

On the other working bones, the bone is also listed under the "deform" tab

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your bone has the "deform" option unchecked

[image]

Comment: yes, fixed it... kinda feel dumb now, thank you! :D

Comment: I know that feeling :)